# Salesforce Bulk API: InvalidSessionId (Unable to find session id) when executed on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, salesforce

I'm planning to use the Salesforce Bulk API for a project on Google App Engine. I've started writing some simple test code to create two Tasks using the Bulk API via the Python [salesforce-bulk-api](https://github.com/safarijv/salesforce-bulk-api) library:

```
from salesforce_bulk_api import SalesforceBulkJob

header = ['WhoId', 'Subject']
messages = [('[...]', 'Test Task 1'),
            ('[...]', 'Test Task 2')]

os.environ['SALESFORCE_INSTANCE'] = '[...]'
os.environ['SALESFORCE_SECURITY_TOKEN'] = access_token

job = SalesforceBulkJob('insert', 'Task')
job.upload(
    header,
    messages
)

results = job.results()
for r in results:
   print('Result ' + str(r))
```

Executing this code locally works as expected and the two Tasks appear in Salesforce. But running the code on Google App Engine, it fails. The job / batch details are:

```
<error xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
<script/>
    <exceptionCode>InvalidSessionId</exceptionCode>
    <exceptionMessage>Unable to find session id</exceptionMessage>
</error>
```

From what I see in the documentation, session ID needs to be sent via header field `X-SFDC-Session` each time. I've checked that and it is set when executing locally as well as via Google App Engine. Headers looking like this:

```
{ 'Content-Length': '183',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'Accept': '*/*',
  'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.9.1',
  'X-SFDC-Session': u'[...]',
  'Connection': 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Type': u'application/xml; charset=UTF-8'}
```

Anyone having tips how to debug / resolve this issue? Thanks!

– Manfred

Comment: Is this still an ongoing issue? It may be worth [reporting on the project issue tracker](https://github.com/safarijv/salesforce-bulk-api/issues). There's a [pull request mentioning unicode](https://github.com/safarijv/salesforce-bulk-api/pull/4), but it's unclear if this addresses your issue.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is an issue with the underlying library. Notice in your error that you're seeing `u'[...]'` where it looks like a simple string should be.

In your local version of the library, in the `salesforce_bulk_api.py` on line 212, locate the following line:

```
headers = {'X-SFDC-Session': self.session_id}
```

and change to:

```
headers = {'X-SFDC-Session': str(self.session_id)}
```

Now, redeploy your app and try again. If this corrects the problem, consider sending a pull request to edit that library to include your fix.

The local development environment is just an emulator and can be significantly different than the real App Engine environment and can even differ substantially from one local machine to another. Many companies will deploy their apps first to a "staging" project prior to rolling the change over to their production projects.

Comment: Good catch. Unfortunately this makes no difference.

I'm aware of the significant differences, that's why we use a staging project on GAE as well. But this time I'm struggling with tracking down the issue / differences..